# Scheduling jobs based on cron expressions stored in DB using quartz scheduler in spring boot application

Tags: database, spring-boot, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have a application with SpringBoot and Quartz which executes only a single job using a Cron expression defined for that particular job.

```
@Bean
public Trigger simpleJobTrigger(@Qualifier("simpleJobDetail") JobDetail jobDetail) {

    CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
    factoryBean.setStartDelay(0L);
    factoryBean.setName("trigger");
    factoryBean.setStartTime(LocalDateTime.now().toDate());
    factoryBean.setCronExpression("0/5 * * * * ?");
    factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);

    try {
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return factoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Now, I am in the need of creating multiple jobs which should be triggered based on their own cron expressions which are kept in database. In above case, the entire project had only one cron, hence I had no issues there. But now, different jobs should have different schedulings.

How can I extend my current implementation to support multiple jobs with different crons?